# delphi no address specified after grabbing ip from dns lookup

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp

Ok, I am getting very frustrated with this, and want to ask for your help before I throw my computer out my window. I am messing with sockets, and I wrote piece of code to get the ip from DNS that I provide. If I do the command showmessage(getipfromdns('test.no-ip.org'));

it will show the ip address no problem.

However if I try client1.Host/address(I have tried both)
client1.Host := getipfromdns('test.no-ip.org');

and throws me an error saying no address specified.

here is the function to get the ip from dns

```
function getipfromdns(HostName: string): string;
type
  tAddr = array [0..100] of PInAddr;
  pAddr = ^tAddr;

var
  I: Integer;
  WSA: TWSAData;
  PHE: PHostEnt;
  P: pAddr;
begin
  Result := HostName;
  WSAStartup($101, WSA);
  try
    PHE := GetHostByName(pChar(HostName));
    if (PHE <> nil) then
    begin
      P := pAddr(PHE^.h_addr_list);
      I := 0;
      while (P^[i] <> nil) do
      begin
        Result := (inet_nToa(P^[i]^));
        Inc(I);
      end;
    end;
  except
  end;
  WSACleanup;
end;
```

and here is the code for when the form is created.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  duchost : string;
begin
  duchost := getipfromdns('test.no-ip.org');
  Client1.Address := duchost;
  Client1.Active := True;
end;
```

(client1 is type TCPServerSocket)

Comment: What type is Client1?

Comment: If `ShowMessage` gives you the address you're expecting, then it seems to me you're basking up the wrong tree by focusing your investigation on `getipfromdns`. Instead, try assigning a hard-coded address to your client object and investigate *that* side of the issue since that's obviously where the exception is being raised.

Comment: @Jan sorry client1 is the tcpsersocket name, and chatclient1 is the tcpclientsocket.

Comment: If you're going eat your exceptions, expect some indigestion. Start by deleting the lines: **try**, **except** and **end**. Currently if something goes wrong, you're just ignoring it. -So how can you expect it to work?

Answer (score 0):

gethostbyname() can potentially return multiple addresses for a given hostname. You are looping through the entire list but only returning the last IP in the list. That is the wrong thing to do.  You need to loop through the list, attempting to connect to each IP one at a time until one succeeds or the list is exhausted.